# Does the Google Maps API v3 require API keys?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Is there a need for API keys for Google Maps API v3? Some documents state an API key is needed for all versions of the Maps API, but other  documents say API keys are *not* required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup), the official answer is **no**, but it would still be useful to sign up for an [APIs console key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key) as it will allow you to monitor your application's Maps API usage.

Answer (score 2):

Starting June 11, 2018 API Keys are required for the maps api.  They are no longer accepting key-less requests

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing?hl=en_US